# react $ doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
  alert('Save ${this.state.course.title}');
```

the above dons't seems to work , am i doing some think wrong?

i have listed the full code which should just display the text entered in the text box in the dialog when save is clicked

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class CoursePage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props, context){
    super(props,context);

    this.state = {
      course: {title: "" }
    };

    this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);
  }

  onTitleChange(event){
      const course = this.state.course;
      course.title = event.target.value;
      this.setState({course: course});
  }

  onClickSave(){
    alert('Save ${this.state.course.title}');
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
        <h2>Add Course</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          onTitleChange={this.onTitleChange}
          value={this.state.course.title} />

        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Save"
          onClick={this.onClickSave} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CoursePage;
```

and also this doesn't allow me to enter an test , is this because of course: {title: "" } ?

i am trying learn react / redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed

```
onTitleChange={this.onTitleChange}
```

to

```
onChange={this.onTitleChange}
```

Duh!

Answer (score 1):

Template strings use back quotes:

```
alert(`Save ${this.state.course.title}`);
```